# Is there a Drupal Module to connect to the StackExchange API?

Tags: drupal, stackexchange-api

I'm looking to connect to the StackExchange API via drupal. I've searched the modules on D.O and have not found one that is suitable. Wondering if anyone has done this integration?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an Obsolete module in drupal 6:

https://drupal.org/project/stackoverflow

Probably, you can pick it & modify as per your need.

Comment: Reviewed that one, seems to be focused on "flair". Ended up building one from scratch, will contribute to drupal.org when it is in good alpha shape